# Turn the Python 2D matrix/list into a table

Tags: python, list, matrix, 2d, tuples

How can I turn this:

```
students = [("Abe", 200), ("Lindsay", 180), ("Rachel" , 215)]
```

into this:

```
Abe     200
Lindsay 180
Rachel  215
```

EDIT: This should be able to work for any size list.

Answer (score 5):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> students = [("Abe", 200), ("Lindsay", 180), ("Rachel" , 215)]
>>> for a, b in students:
...     print '{:<7s} {}'.format(a, b)
...
Abe     200
Lindsay 180
Rachel  215
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: someone changed a key detail of the question** 
Aशwini चhaudhary gives an excellent answer. If you are not in a position of learning/using string.format right now then a more universal/algorithmic way of solving the problem is like this:

```
for (name, score) in students:
    print '%s%s%s\n'%(name,' '*(10-len(name)),score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rjust and ljust:

```
for s in students:
    print s[0].ljust(8)+(str(s[1])).ljust(3)
```

Output:

```
 Abe     200
 Lindsay 180
 Rachel  215
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Python 3.6+** you can use **f-string** for a **one-line** version of Ashwini Chaudhary's answer:

```
>>> students = (("Abe", 200), ("Lindsay", 180), ("Rachel" , 215))
>>> print('\n'.join((f'{a:<7s} {b}' for a, b in students)))
Abe     200
Lindsay 180
Rachel  215
```

If you don't know the **length** of the longest string in your list you can **calculate** it as below:

```
>>> students = (("Abe", 200), ("Lindsay", 180), ("Rachel" , 215))
>>> width = max((len(s[0]) for s in students))
>>> print('\n'.join((f'{a:<{width}} {b}' for a, b in students)))
Abe     200
Lindsay 180
Rachel  215
```