# Turn list into table in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d, tuples

How can I turn `students = [("Abe", 200), ("Lindsay", 180), ("Rachel" , 215)]`

into:

```
Abe     200

Lindsay 180

Rachel  215
```

This should be able to work for any size list.

Comment: The same way you ask for "matrix": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673924/how-can-i-turn-random-matrix-into-a-table

Comment: I am not clear on your desired final form.  Are those strings?  Are the blank lines between the strings part of the desired output?  How do you want the second column aligned?

Comment: You've been asking this same question all afternoon. Is there something wrong with the excellent answers you got here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670097/turn-the-python-2d-matrix-list-into-a-table/22670113#22670113

Comment: It's homework and he's a newbie?

Answer (score 2):

```
students = [("Abe", 200), ("Lindsay", 180), ("Rachel" , 215)]
for student in students:
    print(*student, sep='\t')  # python 3

for student in students:
    print '\t'.join(str(i) for i in student)  # python 2
```